# Prevent user from viewing and editing /var/www folders

Tags: permissions, apache2, users

I need to be able to restrict a secondary user that I'm creating from even viewing `/var/www` as it contains some sensitive information in its PHP files.

Currently, the user is able to view the files (but not modify them). How can I prevent them from even viewing the files without disallowing my web server (apache) from being able to read and execute them?

Comment: Could you add the output of `ls -l /var/www`? Also, this user will have console access to the server, or just viewing the files from the web server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use Access Control Lists. They are a more advanced way of handling permissions than the default way. For example, in your case you can use:

```
setfacl -R -m u:username:--- /var/www
```

More about:

- [Ubuntu Access Control Lists](http://beginlinux.com/server_training/server-managment-topics/1038-ubuntu-804-access-control-lists)
- [`man setfacl`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/setfacl)

Comment: I think he means the logged in users.

Comment: @Braiam ...a secondary user. If this is not logged, can he see something?

Answer (score 1):

You only have to make sure he's not part of the www-data group and that the others permissions is unset:

```
sudo chmod -R o-r /var/www
sudo deluser USERNAME www-data
```

First set the no read for others mode in /var/www and recursive, second verifies that the user is not part of the group.

Comment: Thanks! It says I can accept an answer in 2 minutes, I'll be sure to mark it

Comment: Uh... Actually, nobody can access my website anymore :-(

Comment: you can revert back the changes using `sudo chmod -R o+r /var/www`