# Set up permissions for a secondary user

Tags: permissions

I have a user that I want to give read and write access to a folder in my root home (`/root/test`)

Is there a way to give them permission to only modify files in `/root/test`, but not `/root` itself?

Also, this is kind of a side question, but how can I prevent this user from being able to view or edit the files in `/var/www`? There are some PHP files in there which contain sensitive information. I have already tried `chmod -R o-r /var/www` but that prevented the webserver itself from working.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setfacl`:

```
sudo setfacl -R -m u:username:rwx /root/test
```

See `man setfacl` and [Prevent user from viewing and editing /var/www folders](https://askubuntu.com/questions/340527/prevent-user-from-viewing-and-editing-var-www-folders/340537#340537) for more about.